# Power series expansion of the minimum eigenvalue of a linear matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series

Let $M(\alpha) = A + \alpha \, B$, where A, B are two $n\times n$ positive-semidefinite matrices, and $\alpha$ is a scalar. Define $\lambda(\alpha)$ as the smallest eigenvalue of $M(\alpha)$, i.e.,
$$
\lambda(\alpha) = \min_{x \neq 0} \frac{x^T M(\alpha) x}{x^T x}.
$$
The function $\lambda(\alpha)$ has interesting properties. For example, it is easy to show that it is a non-decreasing and concave function.

I would like to find the power series expansion of $\lambda(\alpha)$ in a neighborhood around $\alpha = 0$, i.e.,

$$
\lambda(\alpha) = \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 \alpha + \lambda_2 \alpha^2 + \lambda_3 \alpha^3 + \ldots
$$

Note that $\lambda_0 = \lambda(0)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of the first matrix, $A$. If $\lambda_0$ has multiplicity one, then $\lambda(\alpha)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $\alpha = 0$. In this case, the above power series is well-defined.

So far, I have only been able to compute the first few coefficients $\lambda_0, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$ by doing perturbation analysis on the following equality

$$
M(\alpha) v(\alpha) = \lambda(\alpha) v(\alpha),
$$
where $v(\alpha)$ is the unit-norm eigenvector associated with $\lambda(\alpha)$. But I do not have a simple and general formula for generating the expansion coefficients. Any comments/ideas are appreciated!